# Selected attribute of select options is not updating automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple selects on my page, each has multiple options.
However, If I select an option then the attribute `selected` of the option is not updating. Shouldn't this happen automatically?!

**Example:**

```html
<select id="browsers">
  <option value="Firefox">Bing</option>
  <option value="InternetExplorer" selected="selected">Internet Explorer</option>
  <option value="Chrome">Chrome</option>
</select>
```

By inspecting the DOM with the developer console, you should see, that the selected attribute is not changing even after selecting another option.

However I found a workaround. To solve this issue we can use this code:

```
$(document).on("change","select",function() {
    $("option[value=" + this.value + "]", this)
        .attr("selected", true).siblings()
        .removeAttr("selected")
});
```

---

**Example:**

```js
    $(document).on("change","select",function() {
     $("option[value=" + this.value + "]", this)
      .attr("selected", true).siblings()
      .removeAttr("selected")
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="browsers">
      <option value="Firefox">Bing</option>
      <option value="InternetExplorer" selected="selected">Internet Explorer</option>
      <option value="Chrome">Chrome</option>
    </select>
```

This works kind of. However, If I select another option than the default option, e.g. Chrome and reload the page, then the option Chrome is still selected even after reload, BUT the selected attribute still points to Internet Explorer!

Which is the best approach to solve this?
My idea is to run through all selects on `$(document).ready()` and select the option where the selected attribute points to.

But why does this all not happen automatically?
Is it a bug or a feature?

Comment: Try using `prop` instead of `attr`: https://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: `prop` makes it even worse.

Comment: You should't care whether the developer tools tells you it has the `selected` attribute or not. If you try `$(option).prop('selected')` will return true on the selected option. What are you trying to achieve? `$(select)val()` should give you the selected option anyway

Comment: @josec89, thank you very much! I understand, I used your comment to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem before was, that after selecting an option and reloading the page, the option was remembered during page reload, even though the attribute `selected` pointed to another option.

I solved it by calling the function below everytime. The function finds out which is the truly selected option, **even after page reload.**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="downloadSelect" id="select_179">
    <option value="-">Please select</option>
    <option value="link_2748" selected="selected">Deutsch</option>         
    <option value="link_2749">Chinese</option>
</select>

<button onclick="return showSelectedOption('select_179');">Show Option Text</button>

<script>
function showSelectedOption(pSelectID)
{
    var text;
    
     $("#"+pSelectID)
     .find("option")
      .each(function(){
      if ($(this).prop("selected")) {
         
         text = $(this).text();
        }
    });
    console.log(text);
}
</script>
```

Comment: "The problem before was, that after selecting an option and reloading the page, the option was remembered during page reload". I finally get what you meant. I thought the problem was "opposite". Ah, language barriers!

Comment: Yes it is quite confusing. Thx for your attempts though :)

Comment: yeah, and now we can both have a bookmark of good `<select>`-wizardry!

Answer (score 2):

The `selected` attribute defines if an element should be selected on *pageload*. If you post a form with a select element, the chosen option will be the one posted, regardless of the initial selected element.

What do you need the `selected`-attribute for in your case?

**Edit:** Based on your comments I made a fiddle

**Fiddle 1** https://jsfiddle.net/q3fpafov/1 selects like you want

**Fiddle 2** https://jsfiddle.net/bge9bsa7/2/ only files available for a chosen language are shown

I hope it's somewhere along the lines of what you're looking for.
The reason for your option still being selected when you reload is browser based. But the `selected`-attribute does nothing for the usability of the option. Also, it won't change because you don't change the way the HTML-element itself is being rendered (at page load)

Comment: I need the selected attribute to set the option according to the selected language in the frontend. E.g. I have a download portal. If german is selected, then my selects should point to german options which are pointing to german files.

Comment: So do you have a select for language or just for the other things? Or is the language stored in a variable somewhere?

Comment: I have multiple files e.g. manuals in different languages. The user should select which manual in which language he wants to download, therefor he has to use the select. However, if the language is set to "English" in the frontend, then all options are pointing to the option which offers the english manuals.

Comment: I guess what I'm confused about it if the user has selected a language beforehand or on the same page

Comment: You are confusing the frontend language and the selected file language.

Comment: yeah I get that. But where do you determine the frontend language? is it a user setting someone has selected ahead of getting to that page or another select? Because if it's set before the page loads, then you can simply render the select based on that. But if you change the select with jQuery, it will always go back to the first select if you reload the page

Comment: are you looking for something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/q3fpafov/1/

Comment: Your fiddle describes my situation quite good. Now imagine I try to output the value of the selected option if I click on download. This works with the workaround I posted in my question. However, lets assume I selected the file `Manual.no.txt`. Now If I reload the page, then the value is kept for whatever reason, instead of pointing to the selected option. I know this is somewhat complicated, I will edit my question for better understanding.

Comment: I updated my fiddle from https://jsfiddle.net/q3fpafov/1/  to https://jsfiddle.net/bge9bsa7/2/ . Now it makes more sense to me.

When you reload your page it will all reset. If it keeps some values it's browser based

Comment: No, the first fiddle describes the situation. Users should be able to see all files in all languages independent of the language selected in the frontend.

Comment: Allright. Well to keep the selected items, you have to somehow save the language, or the selected options server-side, in a Session-variable, a cookie or something in that direction

Comment: yes thats already solved by my typo3 CMS and not part of the question. I solved it already by writing a jquery function. Look at my answer maybe then you understand what the problem was.

Answer (score 1):

Note: selected="selected" is not necessary, simply *selected* attribute will work as well.

When present, select attribute specifies that an option in select should be pre-selected **when the page loads**.

Also, **the pre-selected option will be displayed first in the drop-down list**.

Those 2 should be only effects of the selected attribute.
Note the keywords - when the page loads. He is either there or not when a browser loads the page.

If you wanna make it dynamic you need to use JavaScript. What do you wanna achieve with this? Having attribute selected on the correct element when reloading page or programmatically select the correct element after the page has been loaded?

If you simply wanna make element selected there is easier way trough either value:

```
    jQuery("#browsers[value='the value of the one you like']").attr('selected','selected');
```

Or by index (mind, indexes start at 0 not 1):

```
    document.getElementById("browsers").selectedIndex = "2";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the `value` of the `select` when it changes to see what it has been changed to.

```js
var select = document.getElementById('browsers');
select.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  localStorage.setItem('browser', this.value);
});

var browser = localStorage.getItem('browser');
if (browser) {
  select.value = browser;
}
```

```html
<select id="browsers">
  <option value="Firefox">Firefox</option>
  <option value="InternetExplorer" selected="selected">Internet Explorer</option>
  <option value="Chrome">Chrome</option>
</select>
```

**edit**

So, I missed the part about storing the value so that it persists when the page is reloaded, and depending on the OP's use case, I would suggest using `localStorage` to save the value when it is changed, and to read from it when the page is reloaded.
I have edited the snippet to reflect this (code is simplified)

Comment: But this wont solve the reload problem because the values are only going to be updated on change. But I already solved it by calling a function everytime if I need to find out which option is selected.

Comment: Yeah, I missed all that stuff somehow.
Depending on the OP's requirements, `localStorage` might be an option.